# BLAST Database error: BLASTDB alias file creation failed. Some referenced files may be missing

Tags: database, alias, blast

I am trying to create a blast database containing all plant sequences in Refseq release. I downloaded all the fasta files from the [ftp site](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/release/plant/).

After discovering that some fasta files were larger than 1000000000 bytes, I split the overly large files into smaller fasta files using the following command:

`awk 'BEGIN {n=0;} /^>/ {if(n%500==0){file=sprintf("chunk%d.fa",n);} print >> file; n++; next;} { print >> file; }' < multi.fa`

Next, I proceeded to create the database using the command:

`for i in *.f*a; do makeblastdb -in $i  -dbtype nucl -taxid_map ../plant_refseq_genomic_taxidmap.txt -parse_seqids  -title plantdb; done`

Starting from over 1000 fasta files, I ended up with 1000 databases, each represented by 9 files (.ndb, .nhr, .nin, .nog, .nos, .not, .nsq, .ntf, .nto), that I want to group into a single alias.

I saved the list of all databases in a txt file:

> plant.10.1.genomic.fna.1.fa
> plant.10.1.genomic.fna.2.fa
> plant.10.2.genomic.fna
> plant.10.3.genomic.fna
> plant.10.4.genomic.fna
> etc.....

And I launched the following command:

`blastdb_aliastool -dblist_file listdb.txt -dbtype nucl -out plantdb-refseq-release -title "plantdb-refseq-release"`

But I am getting the following error:

> BLAST Database error: BLASTDB alias file creation failed. Some
> referenced files may be missing.

What could be the reason for this error and how can I resolve it?

thank you for your help

Comment: I also tried to create alias adding some db one at a time and I menage to create the alias with the first 1018 db over the 1031 tot. If I insert the only one of the db from the 1019th to the 1031th it gives me back the error:

**BLAST Database error: BLASTDB alias file creation failed. Some referenced files may be missing.**

So I thougth there was a problem in one of those db or all of them, but then I tried to make an alias with only the db from the 1018th to the 1031th and it worked.

Is it possible that there is a maximum of db to include in an alias or a maximum in bytes?